# AWS CLI --debug ouputs to stderror instead of stdout

Tags: amazon-web-services, stdout, aws-cli, stderr

We have added the `--debug` flag to all our AWS CLI commands so that we get more information on what is happening during deployments on our CI/CD servers.

The problem is that all `debug` output is written to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, which leads to a lot of messages popping up as errormessages, although they are just debug information.

How can I configure the AWS CLI to output `debug` messages to `stdout`?

EDIT: how can I do this without redirecting `stdout`? If I redirect it I will nog be able to access the debug output on my CD/CI server.

Comment: Looks like you, or someone else, raised https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect stderr to stdout with the `2>&1` construction.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a way to fix this without redirecting.

Comment: Not sure there is anything to fix exactly. It is likely this is the design intent of the `--debug` cli flag.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one, redirecting to `stdout` is indeed what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` from the shell command

`aws commad 2>&1`